# I got confused while studying the Statergy pattern, i.e What is the Relationship between Runtime Polymorphism and Strategy Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism

I got confused while studying the Strategy pattern, i.e What is the relationship between Runtime Polymorphism and Strategy Pattern?

If there is any relationship please explain with an example.

Comment: Well, strategies implement a common interface of extend a common superclass. That's what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: Thanks for your Simplest answer @JBNizet

Comment: I think this definition (the converted form of the original definition of Strategy Pattern) is more appropriate to answer this question.

"Define a family of methods and make sure you've encapsulated each distinct method implementation (algorithm) away into new objects so these objects may be switched out polymorphically at runtime".